# Fibrating $X=\Bbb R^2 / \{0\}$ by breaking up the space with hyperbola?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

Attending graduate school this Fall and need to understand fibrations better. I will be taking geometry and algebra. I've read a neat article [Quanta Magazine Article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-explore-mirror-link-between-two-geometric-worlds-20180409/) on the topic of mirror worlds and symplectic spaces but I'd like to gain a deeper understanding of these concepts.

Consider $X=\Bbb R^2 / \{0\}.$

> How do you fibrate $X$ by breaking up the space with hyperbola $y=k/x?$

I understand this basically for a sphere as our symplectic space, but not for the hyperbola. With a sphere you can just fibrate it into tori, then take the reciprocal of each tori and re-assemble to create another geometric shape.